# How to Leverage Browser Caching for Fonts in WordPress

Tags: htaccess, fonts, headers

I am using WordPress along with Autoptimize and Cloudflare, and using Locally hosted fonts. I can't leverage browser caching on my site.

I tried using Cloudflare Page rules to Leverage 1 year browser caching on all resources.

It worked, and most of my site was getting cached EXCEPT FONTS.

I know fonts are heavy and can have negative impact on performance.

I tried the following code in htaccess file in my server root.

```
# Fonts
# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2  "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|mp4|mov|css|js|json|woff|woff2)$">
        Header add Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header add Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

But it didn't work.

As far as I know the below above code should have done the trick to cache the Fonts and JSON.

Please help me figure out the correct way to implement it.

Warnings about fonts not being cached:

> Leverage browser caching of static assets: 91/100 Learn More WARNING - (2.0 days) - https://milyin.com/superpwa-manifest.json

> Leverage browser caching of static assets: 91/100 Learn More WARNING - (2.0 days) - https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/omgf/neve-google-font-poppins/poppins-normal-700.woff2

> WARNING - (2.0 days) - https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/omgf/neve-google-font-poppins/poppins-normal-400.woff2

> WARNING - (2.0 days) - https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/omgf/neve-google-font-poppins/poppins-normal-500.woff2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mime types don't match your `ExpireByType` directives:

```
$ curl --head https://milyin.com/wp-content/uploads/omgf/neve-google-font-poppins/poppins-normal-700.woff2
...
expires: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 13:24:15 GMT
...
content-type: font/woff2
```

So you should change your `.htaccess`.  Instead of, or in addition to

```
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2  "access plus 1 year"
```

you should have

```
ExpiresByType font/woff2  "access plus 1 year"
```

Here are the correct mime types for fonts:

```
$ grep font /etc/mime.types 
application/font-sfnt               otf ttf
application/font-tdpfr              pfr
application/font-woff               woff
application/vnd.font-fontforge-sfd                      sfd
application/vnd.ms-fontobject                           eot
application/x-font              pfa pfb gsf
application/x-font-pcf              pcf pcf.Z
font/collection                 ttc
font/otf                    ttf otf
font/sfnt                   ttf otf
font/ttf                    ttf otf
font/woff                   woff
font/woff2                  woff2
```

You could use a wildcard rule like:

```
ExpiresByType font/* "access plus 1 year"
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answering. Could you please advice about the JSON file too, which was not caching as mentioned in the question body.

Comment: You could add `ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 year"` to cover all json files.  Fonts are almost never dynamically generated or likely to change.   JSON on the other hand serves many purposes.   Be sure that All your JSON is actually static content before you allow it to be cached for such a long time.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
> ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
> ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
> ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
> ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
> ExpiresByType application/font-woff2  "access plus 1 year"
> ```

You need to determine what mime-type your server is actually using to serve these files by checking the `Content-Type` HTTP response header. It is this that determines what mime-type you should be using in the `ExpiresByType` directive. Looking at one of your `.woff2` requests, it returns:

```
content-type: font/woff2
```

So you would need to use the following instead:

```
ExpiresByType font/woff2  "access plus 1 year"
```

> above code should have done the trick to cache the Fonts **and JSON**

But the above code does not explicitly do anything for JSON? (And the `.json` file you link to seems to result in a 404?) The expected mime-type for JSON is `application/json`, but again, check your server's response headers if you are using mod_expires.

**UPDATE:** Your server *is* responding with an `application/json` mime-type for `.json` requests so you need to add the appropriate `ExpiresByType` directive if you want to cache these files for longer. (However, do you really want to cache JSON files for long periods? JSON files are more likely to be fairly dynamic, not static?)

> I tried using Cloudflare Page rules to Leverage 1 year browser caching
> on all resources.
>
> It worked, and most of my site was getting cached EXCEPT FONTS.

Although your `.htaccess` directives actually set *everything else* to be cached for just 2 days (not 1 year). And Cloudflare is seemingly able to override this.

You are employing "service workers" on your site, which is resulting in a great deal of client-side "caching". It's hard to tell which requests are being served by Cloudflare?

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> # BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
> <ifModule mod_headers.c>
>     <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|mp4|mov)$">
>         Header set Cache-Control "public"
>     </filesMatch>
>     <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
>         Header set Cache-Control "public"
>     </filesMatch>
>     <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
>         Header set Cache-Control "private"
>     </filesMatch>
>     <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
>         Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
>     </filesMatch>
> </ifModule>
> ```

You should change the `set` argument in the above `header` directives to `add` instead. Otherwise, these will likely override the `Cache-Control` headers set by mod_expires (which are set earlier).  Indeed, for these resources there are no `Cache-Control: max-age` directives in the response as you would otherwise expect (set by mod_expires).

These `Header` directives don't target `.woff2` and `.json` files. (Why not?)

Aside: I'm also wondering why you are setting `.css` requests to `public` and `.js` requests to `private`? Why do you need to differentiate the two?

Comment: Thanks. And oh yes, I changed the url of the JSON. I updated the question, and the url for it is https://milyin.com/superpwa-manifest.json

Comment: Well, Cloudflare was supposed to catch everything from https://milyin.com/* and set the Browser Cache to 1 year... Anyways I changed it to 1 week now... Hopefully that'll be good for WordPress.. What you say

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal The JSON file is being served with the `application/json` mime-type - as I suggested in my answer - so you would need to add an additional `ExpiresByType` rule for this.

Comment: Thank You. Will try

Comment: Changing it to "1 week" is not necessarily going to resolve the issue (some of these resources, especially fonts, should be cached for longer). Your site is also using "service workers", so the response you are seeing may not be coming directly from Cloudflare. You should probably update your `Header` directives as well. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Have to admit, I don't understand the code in HTACCESS, I understand PHP very well, but Servers are a gray area for me... Yeah, I am caching the Fonts and JSON for 1 year now... and the ExpiresDefault is now 1 week. And as far as your answer edit is concerned, what you recommend is to change `Header set Cache-Control "public"` to `Header set Cache-Control "public"` to `Header add Cache-Control "public"`

Yes, I never read the code in question. I basically took code from some source on web and edited to suit needs, So you are right, CSS and JS should be same. Will do, and also add JSON too it

Comment: Hey, I updated my question with changed Cache Control headers that include JSON and WOFF... Would be great if you could spread some light on whether these headers are right or not.

Comment: Change `set` (first argument) to `add` (not in addition to, if that's what you are suggesting?)

Comment: Look at my updated question...

Comment: Yes, that should be fine (I now see a `Cache-Control: max-age` header in the response), however, the _font_ is still only returning a 2 day cache time? Have you added `ExpiresByType font/woff2  "access plus 1 year"`? (The response is also coming from a "service worker".)

Comment: Ahhh, based on recommendation from other answer, I made this, it includes JSON, and woff2 and wildcard for fonts `ExpiresByType font/woff2  "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType font/* "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 year" `

Comment: Looks fine to me over here: https://snipboard.io/xRBs34.jpg

Comment: That's basically the same as what I suggested above, except for the wildcard (which isn't necessarily required).

Comment: It's great help of yours, even after answering the question you helped me fine tune my site. Rarely we find such great humans. I appreciate your efforts. And Yes, Yeah That's true just the wildcard was from other answer.. Also Anything else you recommend to cache? or any other cache related thing you would suggest me to do?

Comment: Hey, I checked and the Browser caching still shows time of about 24hrs for fonts, and 30 days for JS, even wheen I have set longer time in HTACCESS... Anyway to override it? 
  https://snipboard.io/KA4Oz5.jpg